# Creating DOM elements in angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have a two buttons "add" and "delete" which adds combo boxes along with those two buttons.

What I want is to add the buttons along with dropdowns in this way:

Scenario:

- 1st add button ---> creates pair of buttons along with combobox below
  it
- 1A ----> 1A is child of 1st add button When clicked on add ---->creates pair of
  buttons along with combobox below it
- 1B ----> 1B is child of 1st add button When clicked on add ---->creates pair of
  buttons along with combobox below it
- Now when the user clicks on 1st add button ---->it should create a
  pair of buttons along with combo boxes right below it but not under
  1B

and same goes on for other pair of buttons on the page and so on..

But right now its working slightly different.

HTML Code:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Text Box</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="ctrl-as-exmpl" ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
            <drop-down user="users[0]"></drop-down>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS file:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .directive('dropDown', function($compile) {
      return {

          restrict: 'E',

          scope: {
            user: '=user'
          },

          controller: function($scope) {

              $scope.addChild = function (child) {
                  var index = $scope.user.children.length;
                  $scope.user.children.push({
                      "parent": $scope.user,
                      "children": [],
                      "index": index
                  });
              }

              $scope.remove = function () {
                  if ($scope.user.parent) {
                    var parent = $scope.user.parent;
                    var index = parent.children.indexOf($scope.user);
                    parent.children.splice(index, 1);
                  }
              }
          },

          templateUrl: 'dropdown.tpl.html',

          link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

          },

          compile: function(tElement, tAttr) {
              var contents = tElement.contents().remove();
              var compiledContents;
              return function(scope, iElement, iAttr) {
                  if(!compiledContents) {
                      compiledContents = $compile(contents);
                  }
                  compiledContents(scope, function(clone, scope) {
                           iElement.append(clone); 
                  });
              };
          }
      };
  });


angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.users = [{
        "parent": null,
        "children": [],
        "index": 0
    }]

    $scope.today = function () {
        $scope.dt = new Date();
    };
    $scope.today();

    $scope.clear = function () {
        $scope.dt = null;
    };

    // Disable weekend selection
    $scope.disabled = function (date, mode) {
        return (mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6));
    };

    $scope.toggleMin = function () {
        $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
    };
    $scope.toggleMin();

    $scope.open = function ($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();

        $scope.opened = true;
    };

    $scope.dateOptions = {
        formatYear: 'yy',
        startingDay: 1
    };

    $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
    $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];

    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
    var afterTomorrow = new Date();
    afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 2);
    $scope.events =
            [
                {
                    date: tomorrow,
                    status: 'full'
                },
                {
                    date: afterTomorrow,
                    status: 'partially'
                }
            ];

    $scope.getDayClass = function (date, mode) {
        if (mode === 'day') {
            var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
                var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

                if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
                    return $scope.events[i].status;
                }
            }
        }

        return '';
    };
});
```

Here's the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/54o6wS9VLTPYRYjIiCep?p=preview)

Comment: Can you explain how it is working differently? Seems to be working just as you want it to work.

Comment: No its not working as I require. Go ahead and click 1st add button once it will add set of new buttons with drop down right?? and when you click the 1st add button the second time its adding the new set of buttons in the last row rather than below current row of button clicked

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want.

http://embed.plnkr.co/xYmbm69krqZ9KVNnS7zr/

```
$scope.user.children.unshift({
                      "parent": $scope.user,
                      "children": [],
                      "index": index
                  });
```

Plunkr Stream: http://plnkr.co/edit/xYmbm69krqZ9KVNnS7zr?p=streamer&s=CXiaSno9MfoIQogk

Comment: No its not working as I require. Go ahead and click 1st add button once it will add set of new buttons with drop down right?? and when you click the 1st add button the second time its adding the new set of buttons in the last row rather than below current row of button clicked

Comment: Please check the plunkr I posted above.

Comment: I did already. Its not what I want. I explained it in my comment. Try what I said in plunker and see...you will get it then

Comment: When I click on add 2nd time, it does add it right below the add button clicked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80650/discussion-between-kittu-and-therodeo).